# XSLT - How to get value from for-each loop and use outside it

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a for-each loop to get data

```
<xsl:for-each select="data/table0/item">
   <xsl:value-of select="UIXsltUtils:BuildLink(tag)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
   <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

-> Result:

```
dap, dinh-vu, iphone 6, mephone8, o-nhiem, bb, sai-pham, xu-phat
```

I want to use this string to set value of an attribute of a div (In other block of xslt code)

```
<div class="clearfix m-t-5" initData="init('{$NeedDataAboveHere}','the-thao')">
```

The result I want is:

```
<div class="clearfix m-t-5" initData="init('dap, dinh-vu, iphone 6, mephone8, o-nhiem, bb, sai-pham, xu-phat','the-thao')">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do this :

```
<xsl:variable name="NeedDataAboveHere">
  <xsl:for-each select="data/table0/item">
    <xsl:value-of select="UIXsltUtils:BuildLink(tag)" />
   <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

to store the result of your for-each.

Then the line

```
 <div class="clearfix m-t-5" initData="init('{$NeedDataAboveHere}','the-thao')">
```

should retrieve the desired value.

Comment: But drop the disable-output-escaping. For a start, there's nothing here that needs escaping and therefore no reason to disable it. Secondly, XSLT 1.0 processors are inconsistent about whether d-o-e works when you're writing to a variable (rather than to a serialized final result).

Comment: Okay, I corrected the answer. Indeed I pasted the `<xsl:for-each>` snippet from the question and didn't pay much attention to that.